# Restricted Area for EE2

Tags: members, member-management, permissions, restricted-area

Does anyone know if there is a way to do what Restricted Area for EE1 does but for EE2?

https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/restricted-area

This is a hugely important feature that would allow members to be given specific permissions not only based on which group they belong to, but also on a member specific level as well.

So for example, the user belongs to Group A which has only access to Channel A. Another user belongs to Group B which has access to Channel A, Channel B and Channel C. This feature would allow another user from Group A to also have access to Channel B only (alongside their Group A permission of Channel A).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

SPO far as I can tell, the only comprehensive multiple membership capability for EE is [HooBlong Multiple Memberships](https://www.debeer.com/index.php/debeer/expressionengine_meet_multiple_memberships)

Comment: Looks very promising...quite expensive, but promising.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can restrict channel access on per-group basis natively in member group preferences.

To restrict access to individual entries, or on per-member basis, consider [Entry Access](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/entry-access).

[Member Categories](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/member-categories) might also be helpful if you need to restrict access on category basis.

Comment: Thanks! Isn't Entry Access for specific entries only though? I need to be able to provide channel access on a per-member basis...or does it do that as well?

Comment: Yes, it works on per-entry basis